# Go a holiday vs Go on a holiday

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I know we can "go on a holiday", and I think it is British. But does "Go a holiday" exist?
If so, how is it used? Can it be used in all tenses?

I have come across the following sentence, though, I am not sure if it is just a typo, but regardless of that, can one say:

> Have you ever gone a holiday that mixed business and pleasure?

Comment: That Google books example you found makes no sense to me. It seems garbled. Do you have a link so we can see it in context?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is [prompted by an OCR error](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OzJFAAAAYAAJ&q=%22while+and+then+went+a+holiday%22&dq=%22while+and+then+went+a+holiday%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PyjNVMadE4fZarXvgrAP&redir_esc=y). The text *"were delayed in Honolulu quite a while and then went"* is part of an adjacent column, and shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: It's true that the Google book quote was an OCR error & thanks for spotting that, but the question in fact was never prompted by the error you mentioned. The prompt was from the first quote **"I have come across the following sentence"**. And I looked up the phrase "go a holiday" in the present perfect form before checking with Google book and found some results but I cannot trust any. More on the next comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no phrase "go a holiday" in standard English.

In British English one can *go on holiday*. In American English, one usually *celebrates a holiday* and *goes on vacation.*

Of course you can have a string *go* plus *a holiday* such as in

> Wherever they go, a holiday follows.

This is grammatically correct and even a sentence someone might possibly say or write. But *go a holiday* is not a phrase in it.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much. I was afraid that "go on **a** holiday" wrong but it seems we can say "go on holiday" and "go on **a** holiday!" i.e. with and without "**a**" with the latter more common.

Comment: Yes you can say the phrase with or without **a**. I repeat, however, that *go on holiday* is BrE. It is not AmE. And I also stress that the usual equivalent in American English is not *go on a holiday* but *go on (a) vacation.*